# Spring Integration receive and send xml messages to client through socket connection using java config

Tags: xml, sockets, spring-boot, spring-integration

In my spring boot application, Socket server connects to client to receive message in xml format and send acknowledgement back in xml.

I tried to develop basic socket client server which sends only string messages and it worked. I am confused on how to receive xml file using spring integration?I looked at the [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/xml.html) but I need to develop using java config

Below is my server code for accepting string input

```html
@Transformer(inputChannel="fromTcp", outputChannel="toChannel")
public String convert(byte[] bytes) {
    System.out.println("convert: " + new String(bytes));
    return new String(bytes);
}

// Server
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="toChannel", outputChannel="toTcp")
public String lowerCase(String in) {
    System.out.println("upCase: " + in.toUpperCase());
    return in.toLowerCase();
}
```

1. How to receive xml file in @Transformer . I only need to get the xml file as is and save it in cache(No need of unmarshal to JAXB model).  What has to be in methods for @Transformer and @ServiceActivator? should I convert Document to bytes?
2. For sending xml files as acknowledgment to client, how to build xml and send to client using spring integration

Comment: You need to share more info what does that mean `to parse`. Is just `org.w3c.dom.Document` enough for you? Do you need to unmarshal it into the JAXB model? Why just plain XPath on the string is not enough for you? In other words your question isn't clear. There is a section in the beginning of that Reference Manual to bring some link between XML and Java configs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Well, still unclear. You create a `String` from the `byte[]` which really represent the content of the file. There is no file as an object to be transferred over the network via socket. Fully unclear what is your concern.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Do you mean to say that, create the String from byte[] in  and then get the String and build and xml using org.w3c.dom.Document which can then be saved in cache?

Comment: I still don't understand why simple `String` is not enough for you? You always can convert it into anything else afterward. I would even say that `byte[]` is enough for me to operate. Or you don't tell something else regarding your business logic or I just don't understand your request and therefore can't help you here. Sorry for being so useless.

Comment: I am still not sure how the third part client sends the requests. I only have a sample xml message for reference. as far as your comments I understand that anything(either doc, file or string) sent from client is received as byte[].So I need to convert the byte[] to required form?Am I correct?

Comment: Right, you need. But not clear what is that *required form*...

Comment: Required form is an xml document. I tried with the information you shared to get an xml string, transform it to Document and sending to direct message channel. But now I have a cache which should subscribe to this channel to store the message.I have a controller which invokes service and the service calls the cache. I have no clue how the message can be forwarded to cache through controller. This is absolutely new for me, hence I am not clear with the wording.Apologize for that.

Comment: Yeah... I understand. So, you need to did and read more and more to make yourself familiar with the topic. Anyway your controller is something new in this discussion. You might need to take a look into the Caching support in Spring.

Comment: Yeah I will explore the topic indepth.Thanks for your support